# Find and change Value in multidimensional Array if there is a duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with two dimensions. It looks like this:

```
Array (
[TOKEN] => c374fe5a38b49940b7794ea44185,
[0] => Array (
    [ID] => 1,
    [TITLE] => Product_1,
    [PRICE] => 14.99,
    [QTY] => 1,
    )
 [1] => Array (
    [ID] => 2,
    [TITLE] => Product_2,
    [PRICE] => 14.99,
    [QTY] => 1,
    )
)
```

I want to increase the value of quantity by one if there is a product with the same ID.

My Code looks like this:

```
    // PRODUCT DATA
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$pid'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    // PRODUCT ARRAY - PREPARE FOR INSERT IN ARRAY
    $product = array(
        "ID"    => $row['id'],
        "TITLE"    => $row['title'],
        "PRICE"    => $row['price'],
        "QTY"    => "1"
    );

    function array_search_recursive($needle, $haystack) {
        foreach ($haystack as $value) {
            if (is_array($value) && array_search_recursive($needle, $value)) return true;
            else if ($value == $needle) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // PRODUCT ALREADY IN CART ARRAY?
    if(array_search_recursive($row['id'], $_SESSION['CART']) == TRUE){

       // INCREASE QTY BY ONE

    } else {

        // ADD PRODUCT TO ARRAY
        array_push($_SESSION['CART'], $product);

        return true;

    }

}

if(sh_add_cart($_GET['pid']) == TRUE){

    echo "PRODUCT ADDED.";

} else {
    echo "NOT ADDED.";
}
```

Comment: Where is this other product ID???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes to your code which should do what you want to achieve:

```
// PRODUCT ALREADY IN CART ARRAY?
if(array_search_recursive($row['id'], $_SESSION['CART']) == TRUE){

   // INCREASE QTY BY ONE
   foreach ($_SESSION['CART'] as $key => $item) {
       if(is_array($item) && isset ($item['ID'] && (int) $item['ID'] === (int) $row['id']) {
           $_SESSION['CART'][$key]['QTY']++;
       }
   }

} else {
    $_SESSION['CART'][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I get the warning: "illegal string offset "ID"".

Comment: can you var_dump the SESSION and post it here?

Comment: Sure. Here: `array(2) { ["TOKEN"]=> string(28) "a0a0beb54629e3da2781f5d7a4ed" [0]=> array(4) { ["ID"]=> int(1) ["TITLE"]=> string(9) "Produkt_1" ["PRICE"]=> string(5) "14.99" ["QTY"]=> int(1) } } `

Comment: Could you try with the changed answer?

Comment: It's not working, it adds other values from $row to the array. I removed the part in the `else` and added a `return true` and now its working. Thank you.

Comment: If you put the whole code it will be easier for debug :) but as long as your modification work it's ok